# SQS deduplication ID and item updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS queue that triggers a lambda each time a message arrives in the queue.

the message contains information about a product let's called it A. When the lambda is executed it inserts data of product A into RDS.

However, another message will arrive in about 30 seconds containing other information about product A, which will insert data into RDS again.

Is there any method to put some latency on the SQS triggering lambda? 
Also, can the new messages received for product A be processed and the old ones being discarded? I want to use SQS message deduplication in order to use each message received for the product as unique but I am not sure that it's a good fit for this use case?

The other solution was to replace the SQS with a "custom queue", by replacing the SQS with an RDS aurora instance, the lambda will than do a cron on the instance and pick the product with expired TTL in order to insert in the DB but I find this a bit overkill, is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have control on the producer of messages? You can specify delay for each message. p.s. `SQS message deduplication` is only for FIFO queues.

Comment: yes the producer is a lambda function, the delay needs to be reset each time the producer insert the data in SQS and the old message has to be deleted or discarded

Comment: Could you explain why doing two inserts/updates is not viable for you? I understand that you want to wait 30 seconds in order to not do two database writes, is that correct?

Comment: because the DB receives a huge amount of writes which impact the latency of the writes. Most of these writes are useless since the information for product A will put in the SQS queue several times in a short amount of time (1 minutes), which will trigger lambda to reinsert data in the DB several times for nothing. The idea was to wait some time so only the latest data are put in the DB which will decrease the number of writes.

Comment: @Tar, If you use [event source mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html) for sqs, there is `maximum-batching-window-in-seconds` [parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-event-source-mapping.html). The parameter sets "The maximum amount of time to gather records before invoking the function, in seconds". Maybe this could be something to look into?

Comment: yes, this actually works to wait sometime before executing lambda. the other challenge is to insert only recent messages for a specific product in the DB. SQS will send all messages for a specific product to lambda in batch, the lambda have to compare each message by "SentTimestamp" and pick the latest one, but at least this will already reduce the number of useless writes

Comment: @Tar from sqs you can pull max 10 messages at once. So you could compare only this number of messages to pick the most latest one.

Comment: at least this will reduce a bit the writes on the DB. But on the long term, I think it's better to use an intermediate DB (dynamo or rds) or a cache to store the data and pick the most recent ones even though it will add another storing component in the infrastructure

Comment: @Tar if you control the procuder, wouldn't be it easier if the producer was modified not to send "incomplete" messages or wait with sending messages till they are the correct ones to be written?

Comment: I believe that we have a consensus here, that's it better not to tweak SQS to fit that situation (even though we can't really do that well). @Marcin do you want to create an answer? Could show how one _could_ achieve it and how one _should_ achieve it.

Comment: Actually I think adding an intermediary DB that store messages from SQS before triggering the lambda on cron (each 5 minutes) to insert data in the main DB is a bad idea. You will have less writes on the main DB but on the other hand, you will have the same amount of writes in the intermediary DB. It will certainly optimize the latency on the main DB but I am not sure about the cost.  @Marcin actually I don't have the possibility to change to producer behaviour

Comment: @michaelbahr  Thanks for the clarification. I added answer based on the comments and my further thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, the partial solution to the problem is to setup an [event source mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html) between Lambda and SQS.

In the ideal situation, the producer should be modified in that situation. However, since the producer can't be modified, a caching solution (e.g. ElastiCache) to store the "incomplete" sqs messages before writing them to RDS and to filter out duplicates could be implemented.